# Importing libraries in .java tabs in processing

Tags: java, processing, libraries

I'm kind of new with Processing 3.*; I am (and willing to) using the Processing Development Environment (The official IDE).
Reading the official "guide", in particular [this part](https://processing.org/reference/environment/#Tabs), it is specified that you can use pure Java language inside Processing simply naming a **.java** tab instead of a **.pde** one.

This kind of solution is good for example to use **enum**s (otherwise not usable in .pde tabs) and there are other reasons, but they are not important at the moment...

A problem with this kind of work is that the libraries of Processing are **not** included, so you have to import them manually.

What I noticed is that all the official Processing libraries can be imported simply by the import keyword, while for all the libraries installed by the Contribution Manager the story is different.
The error message is `The package "packageName" does not exists. You might be missing a library. Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.`

Long story short I can't import those libraries...

I tried to copy them in the standard java libraries location (**%SystemRoot%\Java\lib\ext**) and in some other paths, but nothing...
I read that using **classpath** would allow as to use it but I can't understand how to use Processing with javac.

I also tried something like **"ProcessingFolder\processing-java.exe" --sketch="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" --run** that is the same script you can use to run Processing in Notepad++, adding the statement **--classpath="$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"** (Obviously in Notepad++) but it didn't work (processing-java.exe state `I don't know anything about --classpath=.`).

So here's the question: *How can we import and use libraries in .java tabs using Processing Development Environment?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound right. You should be able to use library classes just fine by importing them in a `.java` tab.

**Step 1:** From the PDE, go to `Sketch` -> `Import Library`, then choose the library you want to include. Notice that if you haven't included a library before, it's actually two steps: first you have to install the library, then you have to include it.

**Step 2:** Once you've included a library in your sketch, you can use the classes from that library anywhere in your sketch. This includes `.java` tabs.

Here's an example that uses the `minim` library in a `.java` tab. I didn't have to copy any files or create any directories:

Main sketch tab:

```
void setup(){
  Test test = new Test(this);
}
```

Test.java tab:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

import ddf.minim.Minim;
import ddf.minim.AudioPlayer;
import ddf.minim.AudioInput;

public class Test {

  Minim minim;
  AudioPlayer player;
  AudioInput input;

  public Test(PApplet sketch) {
    minim = new Minim(sketch);
    player = minim.loadFile("song.mp3");
    input = minim.getLineIn();
  }
}
```

It sounds like you aren't properly including the library in your sketch. Make sure you go through the `Sketch` -> `Import Library` menu, and make sure you both install **and** include the sketch.

Comment: Hi!
I actually tried this before: I installed a wrapper of JBox2D by Daniel Shiffman in Processing with the Contribution Manager, then I tried to import those libraries with the `Import Library` sub-menu. It actually wrote an import line code but it didn't worked... I didn't tried with others libraries, though!
Anyway, just creating the folder `code` in the sketch folder just works fine [:

Comment: Update: It **does** work.
I missed to import it **also** in the `.pde` tab.

Comment: @IngrossoD Yep, you have to import it in any tab you want to use it in.

Comment: Any tab that has to use it and for some reasone also the .pde, even if it doesn't make use of it!
Thank you Kevin [:

Comment: @IngrossoD Hmm no that doesn't make a lot of sense. Keep in mind that `import` statements don't actually **do** anything. They're just a shortcut to avoid using the **fully qualified name** everywhere. Also notice that I don't have any `import` statements in my main sketch tab, and it works fine. I'd guess that you are indeed using the library somewhere in your main sketch, but without seeing a [mcve] that's just a guess.